# Which bit represents which TCP flag?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, filter

For instance, a WireShark capture filter example I found - `tcp[13] & 8 == 8` represents packets with PSH flags.

How do I count the `8` ?

Based on the wikipedia image, 
[image]

PSH is in the middle of the TCP flags segment. Counting 1 from the NS flag, PSH bit representation should be 6 ?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [tcpdump man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html), "Capturing TCP packets with particular flag combinations" section - it's a lots of details here.

Answer (score 0):

Time to read up on binary arithmetic! To grab the Nth rightmost bit from a byte, you do `byte & (1 << N)`, so the rightmost bit is `byte & (n << 0)` and the 4th from the right is `byte & (n << 3)`, which is the same as `byte << 8`.

Comment: Oh the 8 is in terms of binary ? Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

You're also starting to count from the wrong place.  NS may be the first flag, but it's also the end bit of byte 12.  Byte 13 (as in `tcp[13]`) starts at bit 8 of line four (labelled "octet 12"), and runs to bit 15 on the same line.